# How to the the Activity from an custom element inside a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

At the beginning I was declaring a custom view element in a layout inside a Fragment, and I was trying to use the hardware acceleration for this component, so the following code in the constructor's view was working perfectly:

```
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

            Activity parent = (Activity) getContext();

            // using the activity, get Window reference
            Window window = parent.getWindow();

            window.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
            Log.d("aaaa",""+isHardwareAccelerated());
```

But now I need to use the same component inside a DialogFragment, meaning that the context won't be the activity. I was trying several approaches, but I can not find any solution for that, besides accelerate the whole DialogFragment itself. Any hint about how I could get the Activity/window/ in order to accelerate only this component?

Thanks!